# Flutter GetX List

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I use the getx package in Flutter. I want to authorize the operations that the user can access or perform in the mobile application while logging in to the login page. For this reason, I am sending a list called Permission with Json Web Token. I save this list in the list named _maincontroller.perms that I created during the authentication process. Then, before routing in the same class, I pull the list named _maincontroller.perms and when I print, the data appears in the debug console. When it comes to the main screen, I have a sidebar. In this sidebar, the fields that will appear will be seen according to the authority. For this reason, I need to use the authorizations saved in _maincontroller.perms in the sidebar, but when I print _maincontroller.perms in my sidebar widget, it appears empty.

This is my MainController;

```
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

import 'package:get/get.dart';

class MainController extends GetxController {
  late List<dynamic> perms = <dynamic>[].obs;

  final String apiUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api";
  var token = "".obs;
  var userid = "".obs;
  var name = "".obs;
  var surname = "".obs;
  var isLogged = false.obs;
  var isSuccess = false.obs;
}
```

this is my auth_controller

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print, use_build_context_synchronously

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:material_tracking/Controllers/main_controller.dart';
import 'package:material_tracking/Services/GetToken.dart';
import 'package:jwt_decoder/jwt_decoder.dart';

class AuthController {
  MainController _mainController = MainController();
  Future loginUser(String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      final _url = _mainController.apiUrl + '/Auth/Login';
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(_url),
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({"email": email, "password": password}),
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        GetToken result = getTokenFromJson(response.body);
        Map<String, dynamic> decodedJwtToken =
            JwtDecoder.decode(result.data.accessToken);

        if (result.isSuccessful == true) {
          _mainController.token = result.data.accessToken.obs;
          _mainController.isSuccess = result.isSuccessful.obs;
          _mainController.perms = decodedJwtToken["Permission"];
          print(_mainController.perms); 
          if (_mainController.isSuccess == true) {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/dashboard");
          } else {
            print("Hata");
          }
        } else {
          print(result.error);
        }
      } else {
        print("Login Error");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exception: $e");
    }
  }
}
```

This is sidebarnavigation widget

```
var permissionList = [];
final MainController mainController = Get.find();

late List<dynamic> perms;

class _SideBarNavigationDrawerState extends State<SideBarNavigationDrawer> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    perms = mainController.perms;
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(perms);
    }
  }
```

This is model.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final getDecodedJwt = getDecodedJwtFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

GetDecodedJwt getDecodedJwtFromJson(String str) =>
    GetDecodedJwt.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String getDecodedJwtToJson(GetDecodedJwt data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class GetDecodedJwt {
  String httpSchemasXmlsoapOrgWs200505IdentityClaimsNameidentifier;
  String userId;
  String email;
  String httpSchemasXmlsoapOrgWs200505IdentityClaimsName;
  String name;
  String surname;
  String domainId;
  String fullName;
  String googleMapApi;
  String jti;
  List<String> permission;
  String aud;
  int nbf;
  int exp;
  String iss;

  GetDecodedJwt({
    required this.httpSchemasXmlsoapOrgWs200505IdentityClaimsNameidentifier,
    required this.userId,
    required this.email,
    required this.httpSchemasXmlsoapOrgWs200505IdentityClaimsName,
    required this.name,
    required this.surname,
    required this.domainId,
    required this.fullName,
    required this.googleMapApi,
    required this.jti,
    required this.permission,
    required this.aud,
    required this.nbf,
    required this.exp,
    required this.iss,
  });

  factory GetDecodedJwt.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetDecodedJwt(
        httpSchemasXmlsoapOrgWs200505IdentityClaimsNameidentifier: json[
            "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"],
        userId: json["UserId"],
        email: json["email"],
        httpSchemasXmlsoapOrgWs200505IdentityClaimsName:
            json["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"],
        name: json["Name"],
        surname: json["Surname"],
        domainId: json["DomainId"],
        fullName: json["FullName"],
        googleMapApi: json["GoogleMapApi"],
        jti: json["jti"],
        permission: List<String>.from(json["Permission"].map((x) => x)),
        aud: json["aud"],
        nbf: json["nbf"],
        exp: json["exp"],
        iss: json["iss"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier":
            httpSchemasXmlsoapOrgWs200505IdentityClaimsNameidentifier,
        "UserId": userId,
        "email": email,
        "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name":
            httpSchemasXmlsoapOrgWs200505IdentityClaimsName,
        "Name": name,
        "Surname": surname,
        "DomainId": domainId,
        "FullName": fullName,
        "GoogleMapApi": googleMapApi,
        "jti": jti,
        "Permission": List<dynamic>.from(permission.map((x) => x)),
        "aud": aud,
        "nbf": nbf,
        "exp": exp,
        "iss": iss,
      };
}
```

i tryed like this
in AuthController print(_mainController.perms); working well
in SideBarWidget print(perms); empty result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to see without seeing the full project but it looks like the problem might be that you are doing

```
MainController _mainController = MainController();
```

inside the `AuthController`. This means that it has it's very own maincontroller that is in no way linked to the mainController in other parts of the app. You might want to do

```
MainController _mainController = Get.find();
```

instead, but again it's hard to judge without seeing the full picture

Comment: Thanks for reply, i changed in AuthController 
MainController _mainController = MainController();
to
MainController _mainController = Get.find();
and restart the emulator it's worked.